# Rails admin "username has already been taken"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails Admin panel in my app. When I try to update one of the existing users(edit user_info field + click save) I got

```
User failed to be updated
- Username has already been taken
```

even though I don't touch the username at all.

All operations are made from admin account. That has `can :manage, :all` in ability.rb

I've already tried adding `on: :create` to the end of `validates :username` but it throwed me a different error.

**How to allow user editing from Rails Admin dashboard?**

**up**

```
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {in: 3..150}
```

after adding `on: :create`

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in RailsAdmin::MainController#edit
SQLite3::ConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique: UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "confirmed_at" = ?, "confirmation_sent_at" = ?, "user_info" = ?, "id" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?


    def each
      loop do
        val = step
        break self if done?
        yield val
      end
```

**up2**

If I try to edit the current user(myself) it works fine.

Comment: Can you please post your model or at least the part with the validators? What is the *different error* that you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my ability class for authenticated users I had this:

```
can :update, User, id: user.id
```

after changing it to the following code, I can edit other users:

```
 can :update, User do |u|
   u.id == user.id
 end
```